# Filling in colors in frame macros

Tags: color, environments, framed, environment-variables

I am hoping the answer to this question is a simple, so apologies for my ignorance.
Based on posts here, I was finally able to make the frame appear the exact way I wanted it to. I made the following macro:

```
% make a box around text {framed}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{framed}{%
  \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin
  \fboxsep=\FrameSep\fbox{##1}
    \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
    \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
    \@setminipage}}%
  {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed}
\makeatother
```

I am now able to create frames around both my admonitions as well as my code. Here is an example:
[image]

My question is: is there a simple way to fill in the admonition frame (note) with yellow and the code frame with light gray?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ca nyou specify what post please so we can relate between ? and provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) please

Comment: From the `xcolor` package: `\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<text>}`, but without an compilable example hard to test.

Comment: Or if you are not emotionally attached to your code fragment, there are great packages like `tcolorbox` which make it easy to add background colours to frames.

Comment: Also there is [mdframed](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) package.

Comment: @Jagath, I tried the mdframed package, but to no avail. For some reason it did not want to work on my system and TecnicCenter threw a rod. I have looked into it, but decided to try other methods rather than re-invent the wheel. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `tcolorbox` version with `sidebyside` for the logo. Please note that such a box is not breakable!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\newtcolorbox{framed}[1][]{
  colframe=lightgray,
  colback=yellow!40!white,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  lower separated=false,
  lefthand width=1cm,
  sidebyside gap=0.5cm,
  sidebyside,#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{framed}
  \bcbombe
  \tcblower
  To measure something use a ruler, a stop watch and scale!
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}[colback=blue!50!green]
  \bclampe
  \tcblower
  Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end!
\end{framed}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I have tried {tikz} and {mdframed} but they did not work on my specific set of .sty files. I am still relatively new at this and am using the Wiley LaTeX outline and also attempting to customize to my needs. Also, I would very much prefer keeping the frame the way I build it. My only complaint about the alternatives is that the horizontal space above and below the text is 3x what it should be. What I shared here is the best frame rendering so far.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will give that a shot and see if I can get better results using your syntax than my own. Vielen Dank!

Comment: @KerryCox: The `tcolorbox` is very configurable. I think you will benefit from it!

Comment: yes, I am seeing that. Your code by itself works wonderfully. However, as I am trying to get a very specific look for my book, I am using the Wiley LaTeX template from Amy Hendrickson at Texnology. Her layout best matches what I want to display. However, I suspect her styles conflict with some of the packages you suggested. After adding your code and building to PDF, I have over 2800 errors. Maybe something other than TecnicCenter? I'd rewrite Amy's template if I were not such a neophyte.

Comment: I don't use such stuff like TecnicCenter (that's an editor, isn't it?) You need to update your TeX distribution. Can you provide a link to this template. You should also be aware that redoing templates might conflict with copyright

Comment: Understood. I realize this and have retained all her comments. I only need to get these extra packages to work and there seems to be a conflict between certain packages and her code, while other packages, like {framed} work fine.

Comment: The sharelatex.com site provides a copy of her template and a couple .sty files. I have looked through those, but do not yet understand the syntax well enough to make heads or tails. I come from a DocBook background but see the wisdom of LaTeX. What do you use for editing your .tex files? I have tried everything under the sun on both Linux and Windows and Mac.

Comment: @KerryCox: I use `emacs`, and compile by hand on a console (on Linux)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41921/discussion-between-kerry-cox-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 2):

Very close to your code fragment, just replaces `\fbox` by `\fcolorbox` from the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{note}{rgb}{1 1 0.5}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{framed}{%
    \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin
        \fboxsep=\FrameSep\fcolorbox{black}{note}{##1}
        \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
        \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
        \@setminipage}}%
{\par\unskip\endMakeFramed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{framed}
        \includegraphics[width=1cm]{bc-crayon} \texttt{Libstdc++} is part...
    \end{framed}

    \definecolor{note}{rgb}{0.8 0.8 0.8}

    \begin{framed}
        \includegraphics[width=1cm]{bc-outil} \verb|mkdir -r bla|
    \end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I redefine the `shaded` environment from `framed` to have a frame, then define  a `note` environment, based on `ntheorem` with option `framed`, as a `shaded theorem`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}
\input{insbox} 
\newcommand\notesymbol{\relax}
\newtheoremstyle{note}%
  {\item[]\leavevmode\InsertBoxL{0}{\enspace\textcolor{Tomato1}{\LARGE\notesymbol\,}}[2]\hspace*{-\parindent}}%
  {\item[]\leavevmode\InsertBoxL{0}{\enspace\textcolor{Tomato1}{\LARGE\notesymbol\,}}[2]\hspace*{-\parindent}}%
\usepackage{framed}
\theoremstyle{note}
\colorlet{framecolor}{Grey0!80!RoyalBlue3!50!}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!45!}
\theoremframepreskip{6pt}
\theoremframepostskip{6pt}
\theoreminframepreskip{4pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{4pt}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{}
\def\notesymbol{\faFileText}
\def\theoremframecommand{\setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
\newshadedtheorem{note}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{note}%
Libstdc++ is part of the GCC sources.  You should first  unpack the GCC tarball and change to the \verb|gcc-5.2.0| directory.
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]